# How to create different Apache Cassandra nodes using different PCs in the same network?

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, cql

I have two PCs connected within the same home network and I would like to share between them a database created with Apache Cassandra. Obviously Cassandra is installed on both PCs. I followed the procedure suggested by https://medium.com/@achraf.elgdaouni/quick-setup-of-a-multi-node-cluster-database-with-cassandra-5b3573579ceb but I think I have not framed the problem. Doesn't this link talk about datacenters within the same machine? If someone can direct me it would be very welcome and helpful. Also, I think it may be a matter of general interest as well.

Comment: no - that tutorial just describes standard multi-node setup, with different machines in different DCs... You may also look into https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide - this is a good free book on Cassandra

Comment: thank you @AlexOtt. I'll read and try.

Comment: @AlexOtt ..but tutorials on the web step-by-step?

Comment: just follow the cassandra documentation on how bootstrap nodes & add nodes